# Eclipse classpath does not update changes in Project Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, classpath

I am using Eclipse 3.4.1 Build M20080911-1700

I have tried to change the classpath directories for jar and the source directory using the Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab or Source Tab. When I click OK button and then return to the properties page, my changes were not applied.

I have to resort in the work around by manually changing the eclipse ".classpath" project settings file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the .classpath file checked into source control? You may not be able to change it if you don't have it checked out.

Comment: The classpath is not checked in the source control but it exist in the file system. I do not also use any plugin to link Tortoise SVN with my eclipse. I just commit them via the windows explorer properties menu. So, I believe that the source control must not prevent the unversioned file to be changed since the eclipse is not source control aware.

Comment: Is the parent directory of the .classpath file in svn? I've had an issue with this before and it definitely was source control related. Not saying this is your issue, but it sounds very similar.

Comment: Yes, the .classpath file is in the svn repository. What is the issue that you had experience?

Comment: In your previous comment you said it is not checked into source control, but in this comment you said it is. I'm confused. But if it is in the svn repository, make sure it is checked out before you try to make changes to it through Eclipse.

Comment: Oh, i got confused in the terminology. I had checkout the whole repository that includes the .classpath file. But what i meant by it is in the svn repository is it is committed in the repository vut is checked out. did you get what i meant?

Comment: I get it now. Just make sure the .classpath file is writeable (check its attributes). If it's not, that's why Eclipse can't write to it.